# Why is my [Op.or] only partially working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, restful-architecture, restful-url

I am trying to write an endpoint for searching for a user with a username or id that matches the passed string. Below is the current code I have set up for an endpoint on localhost at .../api/users/:search.

```
//GET user by id or password
router.get('/:search', (req, res, next) => {
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                {
                    id : { [Op.eq]: req.params.search }
                },
                {
                    username : { [Op.eq] : req.params.search }
                }
            ]
        }
    }).then(data => {
        res.json(data)
    }).catch(next)
});
```

I believe I've set everything up correctly, but I'm only able to get a response when I pass in an existing id. Example: I have a user with the id "1" and the username "hyena12". If I do a GET on .../api/users/1, it will return the user. But if I do a GET on .../api/users/hyena12, the response just says "error".

I am using Sequelize with Node and am using PostMan to try and test this. Postgres DB is being used on the backend.